# Can my eth adress be found through ens domain?

Tags: ens

I have squaded several .eth domains and have since released them, now, I dont want them to be associated with my address. 1. They still pop up when I enter my ens manager, can I somehow make them dissapear and not be linked to my address?
2. Can other people find my address through these ens domains (can they still point to my eth address somehow), even though I have released them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will always be possible to associate the ENS with your address because everything on the blockchain is in read-only. It's very likely that with a little audit we'll find your address.

1. No
2. Yes